# mock a service with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Trying to write a test to provide code coverage for the following code :

note : there are other functions in the service but just listing one for brevity.

```
export const service = {
     getById: async (id) => {
     const url = `/api/customers/${id}/names`
     const {data} = await axios.get(url, axiosOptions);
     return data;
}
```

I'm attempting to simply provide code coverage with this test:

note : I have attempted to use require instead of import but that does not seem to work.

```
import {service} from './requests';

it("mocks the getById function", () => {
     service.getById = jest.fn();

     expect(service.getById.mock).toBeTruthy();
}
```

This test passes however seems to provide no code coverage.

I've attempted to mock out the axios call but I seem to get nowhere as examples I've found of implementations are not working for me currently.

Does anyone have ideas and an example how I could provide code coverage for the service please?

---

Update : to sonEtLumiere's answer

```
jest.mock('./service', () => ({
     getById: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ data : "hello"}),
}));

describe('test', () => {
     it('mocks the service", async () => {
     service.getById.mockResolvedValue({data: "hello});
     const data = await service.getById(1);
     expect(data).toEqual({data:"hello"});
   })
})
```

Currently getting back error :

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getById')
```

Any thoughts on why I'm getting this error?

Comment: You shouldn't mock `service.getById` method if it's the code you want to test and improve the coverage. Instead, try mocking `axios.get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mock a service using Jest, you can use the jest.mock() function to create a mocked version of the service. For example:

```js
jest.mock('path/to/service', () => ({
  getById: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ /* mocked data */ }),
}));
```

Then, in your test file, you can import the mocked version of the service and use the mock property on the function to control its behavior. For example, you can use .mockResolvedValue to set the resolved value of the function, or use .mockRejectedValue to make the function throw an error.

```js
import { service } from 'path/to/service';

describe('test', () => {
    it('mocks the service', async () => {
        service.getById.mockResolvedValue({ /* mocked data */ });
        const data = await service.getById(1);
        expect(data).toEqual({ /* mocked data */ });
    });
});
```

Comment: :-) getting back error. edited original post above ^.

Answer (score 1):

I do agree with `@Lin Du`'s comment, if you want to test `service.getById`, you should be mocking what the method depends on, in this case `axios.get`.

But following along with your question, the issue is that the named export in `./requests` is an object containing the `getById` property which is the method you want to test. So `jest.mock` should look like:

```
jest.mock("./requests.js", () => ({
  service: {
    getById: jest.fn(),
  },
}))
```

Then your test will pass as you expected:

```
it("mocks the getById function", async () => {
  service.getById.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: "hello" })
  const data = await service.getById(1)

  expect(data).toEqual({ data: "hello" })
})
```

But again, if you want to test a method and have proper coverage, what you need to mock is the method's dependency, not the method itself, e.g:

```
import { service } from "./requests"
import axios from "axios"

jest.mock("axios")

test("service.getById", async () => {
  axios.get.mockResolvedValueOnce({ data: "hello" })
  const result = await service.getById(1)

  expect(result).toBe("hello")
})
```